# Invalid Request in Android Signed APK

Tags: android, integration, linkedin-api

I have integrated LinkedIn SDk. It worked fine on debug mode but in release mode it giving invalid request.

I have used this command to create release key hash:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore D:\path\keystore.jks -alias Password | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

followed this: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Not able find a solution ,Please help

Comment: You have debug and release key store (at least you should) you have to add both hashes. It looks like you are missing the release keystore hash.

Comment: can any one tell which is the right way to create release key hash for linked ?

Answer (score -1):

Here're two of possible solutions about your problem.

- Check and add both hashes (release and debug) and don't see any problems maybe you have some problem with proguard.
- If you match your requests' query strings or posted jsons' object labels with your classes' property names and you proguard your domain classes you may have problems with your requests. Check your requests and if you see problem use `@SerializedName` annotation in your domain classes or request bean classes.